# I have a minecraft plugin that detects swear words. How do I execute commands when the player curses?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

Sa as the title says, I have a plugin that detects swear words. What it does now is that it sends a message to the player. But I also want it to execute a command that is already in the game or from another plugin. I'm not sure how to do this. How is that done?
Here is my current code:

```
package



import com.beam.sweardetector.SwearDetector;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.AsyncPlayerChatEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;


public class EventsClass implements Listener {
    SwearDetector plugin = SwearDetector.getPlugin(SwearDetector.class);
   @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoinEvent(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
       Player player = event.getPlayer();
       player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "This server is running AntiSwear v1.0 by BeamCRASH");
   }

   @EventHandler
    public void chatevent (AsyncPlayerChatEvent event) {
       for(String s: event.getMessage().split(" ")) {
           if(plugin.getConfig().getStringList("swears").contains(s)) {
               event.setCancelled(true);
               event.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "§lSwearing is not allowed on this server!");
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute command as player :

```java
event.getPlayer().performCommand("mycommand");
```

But, it will not if the player don't have enough permission.

To run command as console, use this :

```java
Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "mycommand");
```

Also, you don't need the `/` at the beginning of command because it's only to say that it's a command and it can change between players.

Warn: you should run those code in sync. If you are async (specially from `AsyncEvent`), you should use this code :

```java
Bukkit.getScheduler().runTask(plugin, () -> {
   // my code
   player.performCommand("kill");
});
```

Comment: thanks,
sorry for this dumb question but lets say i want to /kill the player - how would I do it so that it executes the target player?

Comment: No problem, don't forget to accept my answer if it well works for you !

Comment: umm, i've edited my comment. again sorry for this dumb question. im really new to java

Comment: also, sadly it does not work. i get a 

[22:10:11 ERROR]: Could not pass event AsyncPlayerChatEvent to AntiSwear v1.0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Asynchronous command dispatch!

Comment: Oh ok. You should use the first mentionned code. You want to run the `/kill`, you should run the command as the player, so `player.performCommand("kill")`. Oh ok, I will edit my answer

Comment: Yes, I just edit my answer, you should use spigot's scheduler to go in sync mode

Comment: now i get a "cannot resolve symbol player"...

Comment: Oh I just make an example. It's just a java writing issue, you should use `event.getPlayer()` instead of player. You can just create a new java variable with `Player player = event.getPlayer()`

Comment: hey, it worked now! Thank you so much!

Comment: one final question. if i want to /title [player] title "some text" it doesnt work. same case would be if i did /smite [player], or /eco take [player] [given amount]. how can i achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work" ? Also, if you need to run command that the player don't have permission to do it, use the second code given in my answer, the `Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "smite or something");`

Comment: i just can t seem to make it work, ill use the second code though

Comment: currently the command code looks like this:
Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "title" + event.getPlayer() + "title test");

so you can see what im trying to do. i want to pass in the player's name so it would execute /title (target player's name) title test. same case would be if i would want to smite the player.

Comment: you forget a space before the "title test" string

Comment: [22:59:53] [Server thread/INFO]: Expected whitespace to end one argument, but found trailing data
[22:59:53] [Server thread/INFO]: ...raftPlayer{name=BeamCRASH} title test<--[HERE]

Comment: Oh, you write `event.getPlayer()` which return the full player object. You should use `event.getPlayer().getName()`

Comment: also i decided to have essentials and have an issue like this as i use the smite command in the code:
/smite CraftPlayer{name=BeamCRASH}. would there be a way to get rid of that?

EDIT: i just saw yuor comment. will test out the event.getPlayer().getName()

Comment: ok, this works. very happy with it. thank you for being so helpful. i really appreciate that!

Comment: No problem, with pleasure ! Also, take the time to learn basic java very well ! I'm sure this can help in some times :)